# VHost Not Working using AWS AMI httpd

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I'm currently creating an application using AWS AMI, and it comes w/ an `httpd 2.4.10`. Here was the steps I followed on creating the vhost

- `sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-available`
- `sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-enabled`
- edited  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to have `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`
- created `realtydig.conf` inside `/etc/httpd/sites-available`
- symlinked it to `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`
- `sudo apachectl restart`
- `sudo service httpd restart`

*still the default httpd page is the one showing, vhost not pointing to domain

here's the vhost

`xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName beta.realtydig.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/realtydig/laravel
        <Directory "var/www/realtydig/laravel/public">
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

I would like to understand, what happened wrong. It seems to be loading up since error occured w/ some of my previous typos when i was trying to restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

If "nothing happened" then I assume that you see just white empty page in browser. Usually some other vhost will be see if current vhost is not activated.

DocumentRoot must be pointing to the public folder like this

`DocumentRoot /var/www/realtydig/laravel/public`

You can debug by creating test.html inside the DocumentRoot and try to access it from the browser.

Comment: No, as in nothing is happening. the apache default page is still the one where the serverName is pointed at.

Not a blank page

Comment: Did changing DocumentRoot to laravel/public change anything? 
How about making copy of the default page chost and changing its DocumentRoot?